# Java print array of integers joined by spaces

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
int arr[] = new int[10];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   arr[i]=s.nextInt();
}
Arrays.sort(arr);
System.out.println(" "+Arrays.toString(arr));
```

my **input** is :

> 98 7 6  5 4 32  14 5 1 7

my **output** is :

> [1, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 14, 32, 98]

but i want to print my output as **sorted number** only but not with [  ] and commas what would be the required solution

Comment: after read the input:


`System.out.println(Stream.of(arr).sorted( ).map( String::valueOf ).collect( Collectors.joining( " " ) ));`

Comment: Morteza's answer is a better performance solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just loop over the array, and print each number.

```
for (int i: arr) {
  System.out.print(i);
  System.out.print(" ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: ..this one worked perfectly..without scratching my mind..but why we are printing index value since we have to print element of that index will you please explain

Comment: In a for-each-loop the `i` is not the index, but the element of the collection you are iterating over. This is different from `for (int i=0; i<10; i++)`

Comment: This has a trailing space which might not be desirable.

Answer (score 4):

Use [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to replace `[` and `]` with empty string:

```
System.out.println(" " + Arrays.toString(arr).replaceAll("[\\[|\\]]", ""));
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to iterate over the array and print the desired string. Another solution is just using substring as following:

```
String result = Arrays.toString(arr);
System.out.println(" "+result.substring(1, result.length()-1));
```

By iterating also you can get this result as following:

```
for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
}
```

Or using regex, you can replace first and last characters as following:

```
System.out.println(" " + Arrays.toString(arr).replaceAll("^.|.$", ""));
```

You can also use `StringUtils`(commons-lang) which is **null safe**:

```
StringUtils.substringBetween(Arrays.toString(arr), "[", "]");
```